# Solr - Disable Core Reload and Unload Option

Tags: solr

Is there any way to disable core reload/unload/rename in Solr admin UI?

I tried and I don't see any. Atleast it should ask for credentials when user click on those options.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should never give direct access for users to Solr without them being administrators.

You can configure Solr to perform [Authentication and authorization](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html) if your Solr version is new enough, or you can stick a reverse proxy in front of Solr and limit the set of URLs the user is allowed to access. But be aware of certain parameters that might allow a user to change the request handler, even if the request goes to an allowed endpoint.

That might not be relevant for the endpoints that make up the core reload/unload/rename in the REST interface behind the admin pages though. You can see which endpoints are used by watching the "Network" tab under developer tools in your browser while using the interface.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. Actually we have restriction over firewall. I want to make solr dashboard visible to few users (different team members)  to check if solr is up or not  and those users should not click on unload or rename buttons from admin url. So, i just want to restrict it.

Comment: Try either the built-in support or use a reverse proxy or an application level firewall (i.e. that can filter on HTTP specific request endpoints).